# Conda fails package installation with Unsatisfiable Error

Tags: r, conda

I'm facing a conda error that I can't explain right now.

After setting up a brand new env with `conda create -n test-env` I try to install the bioinformatics package scater `conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-scater` which ran flawlessly on this cluster (linux) yesterday.

Of course I don't install r-base before, but that should be done by conda itself. Its a completely clean environment.

I'm always ending up with that error from conda:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                            

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - bioconductor-scater -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

Where is that coming from and why is the version of `__glibc` not satisfiable?

Comment: Your version of gcc is out of date.

Comment: How would I update that? The conda installation is new and `conda update conda` only tells me that all packages are already installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bioconda depends on `conda-forge` channel being prioritized. That is one must use:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda bioconductor-scater
```